# Using one stream delete from a list odd integers if their sum is odd, delete even integers if the sum is even

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to implement a method `oddOrEven(List<Integer> integers)`: if a sum of integers values is odd the method should delete all odd elements, if the sum is even the method should delete all even numbers.

The task is to implement a method with the time complexity `O(N)`. I can use local variables, but I should write just one stream.

This is my solution with two streams.

```
private static List<Integer> oddOrEven(List<Integer> integers) {
    Integer sum = integers.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);

    return integers.stream().filter((a) -> sum % 2 == 0 && a % 2 != 0 ||
        sum % 2 != 0 && a % 2 == 0)
        .collect(toList());
}
```

I also tried to calculate sum inside a stream, but this doesn't work as the sum.value is changing during iteration over the `List<Integer>` integers values.

```
    private static List<Integer> oddOrEven3(List<Integer> integers) {
        class IntegerWrapper {
            private int value = 0;
        }

        final IntegerWrapper sum = new IntegerWrapper();

        return integers.stream()
                .peek((a) -> sum.value += a)
                .filter((a) -> {
                    return sum.value % 2 == 0 && a % 2 != 0 ||
                            sum.value % 2 != 0 && a % 2 == 0;
                })
                .collect(toList());
    }
```

Please, help me to figure out how can I solve the task with just one stream? Is there a way to store a sum inside the stream which is not changing during the iteration?

Comment: You could just use a grouping collector to separate the lists of odd and even values. Note: you don't need to calculate the sum to see if it will be odd or even. Even numbers can't change the odd-ness, and only an odd number of odd numbers can have an odd sum.

Comment: You could use [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)) and put the decision which list to return into the finisher, with [`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate)) to separate odd and even numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution

```
private static List<Integer> oddOrEven(List<Integer> integers) {
    final Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> oddsAndEvens = integers.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> i % 2 == 0));
    return oddsAndEvens.get(oddsAndEvens.get(false).size() % 2 != 0);
}
```

It works by splitting the list into 2 lists, odd and evens. Then it chooses which list to return by looking at the size of the odds list.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possibility.

- use the teeing Collector to create two lists, one of odd and one of even
- then return the appropriate list based on the count of odd numbers.  This works since an even number of odds sum to an even number, and an odd number sum to an odd number.  The evens always sum up even.

```
public List<Integer> oddOrEven(List<Integer> values) {      
   return values.stream().collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.filtering(i -> i % 2 == 0,
                Collectors.toList()),
        Collectors.filtering(i -> i % 2 == 1,
                Collectors.toList()),
        (even, odd) -> odd.size() % 2 == 1 ? even : odd));
}
```

Here is another solution as suggested by [@hulk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2513200/hulk) in the comments.  I chose not to use `partitioningBy` but `groupingBy`.

```
public List<Integer> oddOrEven(List<Integer> values) {  
   return values.stream()
        .collect(collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i % 2),
                map -> map.getOrDefault(
                        (map.getOrDefault(1, List.of()).size() + 1)
                                % 2,
                        List.of())));
}
```

The `finisher`, as before, checks the size of the odd list `(map.get(1))`.  To return the `other list` based on the size of the odds, add `1` to that size and then get the remainder for division by `2`.

Thanks to [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) suggesting to use `map.getOrDefault()` to handle absent keys in the final map.